# Unable to 'sh' within declarative pipeline script block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to recreate k8s environment on remote host via bash script and its working fine. When i do the same thing via Jenkins job conditionally, it gives serialization error. Basically, I want that, this periodical job notify me after 20 minutes of continues failed of 'test-job' and after 30 minutes it execute the script.sh which will create new k8s environment on remote host.

**Jenkins Version : 2.204.1**

**Note: The same pipeline works fine within updated Jenkins Version 2.319.1. Please do not ask for Jenkins update**

pipeline Code:

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
pipeline {
    agent any
    options { timestamps () }
    stages {
        stage('Main') {
            steps {
                script {
                    name = "test-job"
                    def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(name)
                    def job_data = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job.fullName)
                    println 'Job: ' + job.fullName
                    //Check if job had atleast one build done
                    if (job_data.getLastBuild()) {
                        last_job_num = job_data.getLastBuild().getNumber()
                        last_job_res = job_data.getLastBuild().result
                        def upStreamBuild = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(job.fullName).getBuildByNumber(last_job_num)
                        if (String.valueOf(last_job_res) != 'SUCCESS') {
                            //Check if job had last one successful build
                            if (job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild()) {
                                println 'Last Success Build Number: ' + job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()
                                println 'Last Success Build Time: ' + job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getTime()
                                after55Mins = findLastBuildTime(20)
                                after60Mins = findLastBuildTime(30)
                                if (after60Mins < upStreamBuild.getTime()) {
                                    def msg = "The production environment is being recreated"
                                    println msg
          // problem here       dir ('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/check-job-status/') {
                                            sh '''chmod u+x script.sh && ./script.sh'''
                                        }
                                } else if (after55Mins < upStreamBuild.getTime()) {
                                    // done notify
                                } else {
                                    println "30 minutes after last successful build not yet completed"
                                }
                            } else {
                                println 'Last Success Number: Null'
                            }
                        } else {
                            println "Last build no. ${last_job_num} of the job ${job.fullName} was successful."
                        }
                    } else {
                        println 'Last Build Numer: Null'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def findLastBuildTime(x) {
    use( TimeCategory ) {
        return Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(Hudson.instance.getJob("test-job").fullName).getLastSuccessfulBuild().getTime() + x.minutes
    }
}
```

and the Jenkins error that i got :

```
Started by user xyz
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/check-job-status
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Main)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
17:47:50  Job: test-job
[Pipeline] echo
17:47:50  Last Success Build Number: 8
[Pipeline] echo
17:47:50  Last Success Build Time: Tue Dec 21 12:00:46 UTC 2021
[Pipeline] echo
17:47:50  The production environment is being recreated
[Pipeline] dir
17:47:50  Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/check-job-status
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@13ffa470
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@35920e8
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@695f5e54
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@1b934431
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@31642a51
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@7c8021aa
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@52f40671
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@249995dc
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@249995dc
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:534)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:445)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Feel free to ask any doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message and stack trace actually imply the issue is at pipeline termination, and not at the shell step method execution. There is a Map somewhere in your code where the marshalling is nonserializeable. It is most likely occurring somewhere a markup language (e.g. YAML, JSON, etc.) is parsed into a Map, but you would need to do iterative testing to find root cause here.